# Primefaces Dialog Framework Liferay

Tags: primefaces, liferay, dialog-framework

Primefaces Dialog Framework  opens  the same portlet page instead of required page.

```
<p:commandButton value="Dialog" process="@this" icon="ui-icon-extlink" actionListener="#{controller.viewDialog}" />
```

Bean:

```
public void viewDialog() {
    Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("draggable", false);
    options.put("resizable", true);
    options.put("contentHeight", 320);

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("viewDialog", options, null);
```

viewDialog.xhtml:

```
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:portlet="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0">
<h:head />
<h:body styleClass="jsf2-portlet">
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{dialog.initController}" />

</h:body>
```

Comment: seems that no one encountered this issue before :(

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if not then add Navigation Rule for "viewDialog" in your faces-config.xml which references viewDialog.xhtml.

```
<application>

    <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
    <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
    <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>

</application>


<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>viewDialog</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>{path}/viewDialog.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by a bug described at [the Liferay forum](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/50202883) and the issue 
[FACES-2168](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-2168).

I was not able to only use the corrected faces-impl with the old liferay (6.1.1).